# SOAP - PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, soap, pkcs#12

I'm building a server that has to call two webservices. Webservices have the same CA certificate (PKCS12).

the first one receives request by GET, the other one by SOAP call.

follow a part of code that creates connection for GET request

```
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            // is https protocol?
            if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {

                trustAllHosts();
                // create connection
                HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = null;
                if(proxy != null){
                    httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                } else {
                    httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                }
                // set the check to: do not verify
                httpsUrlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                setHeaders(httpsUrlConnection, headers);    

                //set del certificato

                log.debug("set certificate for get...");
                File cerp12 = new File(Utils.getWebAppLocalPath(),"WEB-INF"+String.valueOf(File.separatorChar)+PropConfig.getProperty("cer.p12"));
                ((HttpsURLConnection) httpsUrlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(security(cerp12,PropConfig.getProperty("cer.pwd"))); 
                httpsUrlConnection.connect();

                inputStream = httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream();

            } else {
                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
                if(proxy != null){
                    httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                } else {
                    httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                }

                setHeaders(httpUrlConnection, headers);    

                inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            }

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(inputLine);
            }
```

and this part is for SOAP request

```
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            // is https protocol?
            if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {

                trustAllHosts();
                // create connection
                HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = null;
                if(proxy != null){
                    httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                } else {
                    httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                }
                // set the check to: do not verify
                httpsUrlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                setHeaders(httpsUrlConnection, headers);    

                //set del certificato

                log.debug("set certificate for get...");
                File cerp12 = new File(Utils.getWebAppLocalPath(),"WEB-INF"+String.valueOf(File.separatorChar)+PropConfig.getProperty("cer.p12"));
                ((HttpsURLConnection) httpsUrlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(security(cerp12,PropConfig.getProperty("cer.pwd"))); 
                httpsUrlConnection.connect();

                inputStream = httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream();

            } else {
                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
                if(proxy != null){
                    httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                } else {
                    httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                }

                setHeaders(httpUrlConnection, headers);    

                inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            }

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(inputLine);
            }
```

the code is almost the same

with GET request I have no problem, but with SOAP request `httpsUrlConnection.connect();` throws
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is howto create ssl context for HTTPS connection.

```
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = createSSLContext().getSocketFactory();

        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) (url).openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

And method to create SSL context. Note, it load root server certificate from .pem file (x509 format) and client certificate from .p12 (pkcs12 format). If server don't required client certificate, pass null for key managers. If server sertificate issued by authority, which already in $JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts, pass null as trust managers.

And one more note: in .pem file you should store root certificate in PKIX path of server certificate. For example, github.com That site has PKIX path `CN = github.com` -> `CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1` -> `CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` -> `CN = GTE CyberTrust Global Root`. So you store `GTE CyberTrust Global Root`

```
private final SSLContext createSSLContext()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            CertificateException, IOException,
            UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {


        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Config.getString(Config.KEYSTORE_PATH)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("not found keystore file: " Config.getString(Config.KEYSTORE_PATH), ex);
        }
        try{
            keyStore.load(fis, Config.getString(Config.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD).toCharArray());
        }finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
        }
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(Config.getString(Config.HTTPS_SERVER_CERT));
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(null);
        try {
            X509Certificate cacert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
            trustStore.setCertificateEntry("alias", cacert);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keyStore, Config.getString(Config.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD).toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext;
    }
```

Comment: thank's for response, only a thing: what is `Config.KEYSTORE_PATH`? `p12` path or `.keystore` path? And, what is `Config.HTTPS_SERVER_CERT`?

Comment: Config.getString(Config.KEYSTORE_PATH) - property in my config. In your case it is `PropConfig.getProperty("cer.p12")`. HTTPS_SERVER_CERT - path to server certifiacte.

Comment: IOUtils.closeQuietly(in); from apache utils, you can simply close FileInputStream

Comment: Is `HTTPS_SERVER_CERT` $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts?

Comment: No, it is just certificate in x509 format (Only one certificate) Usually it has extension .cer, .crt, .pem Any browser export certificates in that format. But`$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts` is _keystore_ and can contain multiple certificates. Usually it contains all root CA certificates. It loaded by default when JVM starts. Sometimes server uses for https self-signed certificate, and java don't know about CA who issued certificate and don't connect to that server. In that case you should paste service url to browser, get certificate and store it as .pem file.

Comment: Path to that file will be in HTTPS_SERVER_CERT param. Of cource, you can import it in caserts, but usually it not convenient; JRE updates very often and so updates cacerts file.

Comment: I have exported .cer from .p12 through this command: `keytool -export -keystore "[KEY_STORE_PATH]" -alias [keystore_alias] -file certificate.cer`, Can I use that?

Comment: In general, yes, you can, but in practice usually, no. p12 format used to store client, not server certificate. Because it can contains private key. If you need server certificate, just hit wsdl url in browser and export certificate as file. That's all.